# How do I combine the elements of pandas data frames as coordinate pairs?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have tables A and B where

```
A=  [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]
```

and

```
B= [[5, 6],
    [7, 8]]
```

What I would like to return is the Pandas dataframe

```
[[(1,5), (2,6)],
 [(3,7), (4,8)]].
```

How can I do this? I want to do a zip on the elements while preserving the shape of the dataframe. Anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Is a and b data frame ?

Comment: Those aren’t DataFrames. This is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If  both `A` and `B` were Dataframe

```
pd.concat([A.stack(),B.stack()]).groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(tuple).unstack()
Out[24]: 
        0       1
0  (1, 5)  (2, 6)
1  (3, 7)  (4, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip it

`alist = [list(zip(A[i], B[i])) for i in range(len(A))]`

and then convert to a Pandas DataFrame

`pd.DataFrame(alist)`